# Добавить ключ и значение в уже существующий файл JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

У меня уже есть готовые сгенерированные ключи и значения, которые мне просто надо добавить в файл JSON (хранятся они у меня в списке C# в другой функции), который уже существует и в котором уже есть один единственный объект. Нужно добавить новые значения внутрь этого объекта на C#. Еще в конце последней строчки не стоит запятая, ее тоже надо добавить... У кого есть какие идеи? :)

Задача: у меня есть БД, на фото видно, что пользователь ищет определенную таблицу, затем названия колонок таблицы генерируются следующим образом отформатированные под JSON данные. Теперь мне эти данные надо добавить в конец уже содержащего информацию файла JSON (последняя строчка не содержит запятой в конце, об этом надо тоже позаботиться), пример которого на скрине справа[image: скрин]

фрагмент кода по сохранению названий колонок таблицы и их изменению под JSON

```
    string showColumn = "select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'";
    SqlConnection nConn = new SqlConnection(nameConn1);
    nConn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(showColumn, nConn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        optionList.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
    reader.Close();
    nConn.Close();
   textBox2.Text += '"' + optionList[0] + '"' + ":" + '"' + '"' + "," + "\r\n";
    for (i = 1; i < optionList.Count; i++)
    {
        textBox2.Text += '"' + optionList[0] + "." + optionList[i] + '"' + ":" + '"' + '"' + "," + "\r\n";
    }
```

**UPD:**
Так как у меня не было четкого объекта, мне надо было просто работать с json как с текстовым документом. Поэтому о де/сериализации речи и не могло идти, на чем я в принципе и тормозила: как управлять с "динамичным" объектом.

Comment: В чём именно вопрос? У вас есть список, вы можете добавить элемент. У вас есть файл, вы можете де/сериализовать его при помощи Json.Net. Прочитал - добавил - пересохранил.

Comment: @AK Я не совсем понимаю, как добавить именно внутрь объекта, а не просто в конец файла

Comment: Приведите ваш код в задаче, чтобы были понятны структуры данных. Также, меня лично смущает необходимость добавления в определённую точку внутри списка (что бы вы ни понимали под словом "список"), можно же просто ставить в конец, если нет чётких требований по части определённого порядка. Сформулируйте запрос поточнее и приведите код в вопросе - пока слишком мало информации, чтобы отвечать.

Comment: Десериализовать -> добавить ключ -> сериализовать. Всё. Так подходит?

Comment: @AK  приложила объяснения,спасибо за помощь

Comment: @nick_n_a приложила объяснения

Comment: Видите ли какая штука... Вы вообще идёте "велосипедным" путём, создавая свою базу данных в файле - может быть вам стоит в обычную базу писать, получите множество плюшек. Мне кажется, мы вас не уговорим, увы. Это раз. Второе: мы вам предлагаем вариант заново целиком записывать файл, вы в упор не хотите замечать это предложение. Да, будет некоторый оверхед, но возможно он вас устроит? Ответ никто не хочет писать, так как непонятно в какой стороне вам предлагать ответ: толи в стороне где за вас всю работу сделать Json.Net, толи где вы будете по кусочкам вставлять-раздвигать строки в файле.

Comment: И может вам почитать про библиотеку Json.Net, посмотреть, как просто и эффектино с её помощью json преобразуется в объекты c# и обратно?

Comment: @AK вы не совсем правильно поняли, это сделано для того, чтобы создать помощь при переводе данных на другие языки, поэтому мне нужно вставлять в определенный файл. На данном этапе мне просто нужно найти метод их туда добавить, затем уже буду думать над автоматизацией переводов.. Попробую еще почитать про библиотеку, в любом случае спасибо за помощь, просто я еще очень зеленая, закончила первый год университета, а C# занимаюсь с понедельника

Comment: Удачи в работе.

Comment: Можно десериализовать в `dynamic`, если у вас нет "четкого объекта"

Comment: @АндрейNOP делала бы двойную работу, так как мне по сути не нужно было работать с объектом, а просто "редактировать" тест документа. По сути пользователь добавляет в документ ключи, который он хочет перевести на какой-то определенный язык и сейчас я в процессе создания автоматического перевода.